# Checkbox does not display in IE (only)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, checkbox, compatibility

I cannot get my checkbox to be displayed in Internet Explorer.
It works for all other web browsers, but only IE is failing to display it correctly.
Also **it does work properly in my local machine folder, but it fails to display when it get opened from my folder in network (NAS) <- opened with IE**.

Due to work related, it needs to be placed on the network.
I have tested with Firefox 26.0 and IE 10.0.9

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11 DTD/xhtml11.dtd"><html xsi:schemalocation="http://www.w3.org 1999/xhtml http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/SCHEMA/xhtml11.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=windows-1252"/>
<style>
input[type=checkbox] {  
display: none;  
}   
.checkbox label:before {  
border-radius: 1px;  
border: 1px solid black
}  
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {  
content: "X";  
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);  
font-size: 22px;  
color: #000000;  
text-align: center;  
line-height:19px;
border: 1px solid black
}  
label {  
display: inline-block;  
cursor: pointer;  
position: relative;  
padding-left: 25px;  
margin-right: 15px;  
font-size: 16px;  
font-weight: bold;
}  
label:before {  
content: "";  
display: inline-block;  


width: 15px;  
height: 15px;  

margin-right: 10px;  
position: absolute;  
left: 0;  
bottombottom: 1px;  
background-color: #eee;  
box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);  
}      
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" id="Field1" name="testINPUT" fieldname="Vote" mandatory="false" value="VoteYes" /> <label for="Field1">Yes</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" id="Field2" name="testINPUT" fieldname="Vote" mandatory="false" value="VoteNo" /> <label for="Field2">No</label> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: does not work on here on IE ? [link](http://jsfiddle.net/djedjex/5Bwd7/)

Comment: In my IE (8) you can see the fake checkboxes, but not click on them, I think because IE8 doesn't support :checked selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked fine for me with IE9 and above, as expected. Do you really need the conflicting doctype and head declarations? XML version is declaring UTF-8 and meta tag "charset=windows-1252"  We try not to confuse browsers if we can help it.

Comment: After I removed <!DOCTYPE, I can see that original checkbox is displayed (where I initially set as [display: none]), but one that I set in class with "X" to be displayed in the checkbox seems to be still missing.

Comment: I've done that sort of thing and found that it was far more reliable to just use an image as a checkbox and add an click event to it and switch it out as clicked.  If it was in a form I'd change the hidden form value along with the image.  I know it's not a pretty solution but it certainly works everywhere.

Comment: Image tick alternative sounds more reliable for me as well. I've tried with many elements around this issue, but I can't find any reason for this compatibility issue. Thank you so much for the advise, I will give a search around the image as a checkbox solution.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue why Checkbox wasn't showing up
Root of Cause was when the **file was placed on the network and opened with IE**, somehow it automatically change the **Document Mode: to "Internet Explorer 7 standard"**, which wasn't happening when you got the file on your local folder.

So by adding this line in the code will make it force to run under **Document Mode: Standards**

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

For more details about the compatibility, you can find it in the following URL:

https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/#ie8